# How to create columns from multi-layer struct type in spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is the schema of my main data frame:

```
root
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _lineItemId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:FinancialConceptGlobal: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:FinancialConceptGlobalId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:FinancialConceptLocal: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:FinancialConceptLocalId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:InstrumentId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:IsCredit: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:IsDimensional: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:IsRangeAllowed: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:IsSegmentedByOrigin: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:LineItemName: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:LocalLanguageLabel: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:SegmentChildDescription: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:SegmentGroupDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:Segments: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fl:SegmentSequence: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _segmentId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fl:StatementTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction|!|: string (nullable = true)
```

From this my required output is below:

```
LineItem.organizationId|^|LineItem.lineItemId|^|StatementTypeCode|^|LineItemName|^|LocalLanguageLabel|^|FinancialConceptLocal|^|FinancialConceptGlobal|^|IsDimensional|^|InstrumentId|^|LineItemSequence|^|PhysicalMeasureId|^|FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondary|^|IsRangeAllowed|^|IsSegmentedByOrigin|^|SegmentGroupDescription|^|SegmentChildDescription|^|SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel|^|LocalLanguageLabel.languageId|^|LineItemName.languageId|^|SegmentChildDescription.languageId|^|SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel.languageId|^|SegmentGroupDescription.languageId|^|SegmentMultipleFundbDescription|^|SegmentMultipleFundbDescription.languageId|^|IsCredit|^|FinancialConceptLocalId|^|FinancialConceptGlobalId|^|FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId|^|FFAction|!|
4295879842|^|1246|^|CUS|^|Net Sales-Customer Segment|^|相手先別の販売高（相手先別）|^|JCSNTS|^|REXM|^|False|^||^||^||^||^|False|^|False|^|CUS_JCSNTS|^||^||^|505126|^|505074|^|505074|^|505126|^|505126|^||^|505074|^|True|^|3020155|^|3015249|^||^|I|!|
```

To get above output this is what I have tried:

```
val dfContentEnvelope = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "env:ContentEnvelope").load("C://Users//u6034690//Desktop//SPARK//trfsmallfffile//XML")
val dfContentItem = dfContentEnvelope.withColumn("column1", explode(dfContentEnvelope("env:Body.env:ContentItem"))).select($"env:Header.fun:DataPartitionId".as("DataPartition"), $"env:Header.env:info.env:TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"column1.*")
val dfType = dfContentItem.select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"env:Data.fl:LineItem.*", getFFActionParent($"_action").as("FFAction|!|")).filter($"env:Data.fl:LineItem._organizationId".isNotNull)
```

With this i am getting below output

```
 +------------------+-------------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|DataPartition     |TimeStamp                |_lineItemId|_organizationId|fl:FinancialConceptGlobal|fl:FinancialConceptGlobalId|fl:FinancialConceptLocal|fl:FinancialConceptLocalId|fl:InstrumentId|fl:IsCredit|fl:IsDimensional|fl:IsRangeAllowed|fl:IsSegmentedByOrigin|fl:LineItemName                                                                                      |fl:LocalLanguageLabel|fl:SegmentChildDescription|fl:SegmentGroupDescription|fl:Segments|fl:StatementTypeCode|FFAction|!||
+------------------+-------------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|3          |4298009288     |XTOT                     |3016350                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Total Assets,505074]                                                                                |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |BAL                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|9          |4298009288     |XTCOI                    |3016329                    |null                    |null                      |21521455386    |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[S/O-Ordinary Shares,505074]                                                                         |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |BAL                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|10         |4298009288     |XTCOC                    |3016328                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Total Equivalent No of Common Shares O/S,505074]                                                    |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |BAL                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|11         |4298009288     |XTCTI                    |3016331                    |null                    |null                      |21521455386    |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[T/S-Ordinary Shares,505074]                                                                         |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |BAL                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|19         |4298009288     |ESGA                     |3018991                    |null                    |null                      |null           |false      |false           |false            |false                 |[General and administrative expense,505074]                                                          |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|20         |4298009288     |XTOE                     |3016349                    |null                    |null                      |null           |false      |false           |false            |false                 |[Total Operating Expense,505074]                                                                     |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|21         |4298009288     |XIBT                     |3016299                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Net Income Before Taxes,505074]                                                                     |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|22         |4298009288     |TTAX                     |3019472                    |null                    |null                      |null           |false      |false           |false            |false                 |[Income tax benefit,505074]                                                                          |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|23         |4298009288     |XIAT                     |3016297                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Net Income After Taxes,505074]                                                                      |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|24         |4298009288     |XBXP                     |3016252                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Net Income Before Extra. Items,505074]                                                              |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|25         |4298009288     |XNIC                     |3019922                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Net loss,505074]                                                                                    |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|26         |4298009288     |XNCN                     |3016316                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Income Available to Com Excl ExtraOrd,505074]                                                       |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|27         |4298009288     |XNCX                     |3016318                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Net loss,505074]                                                                                    |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|29         |4298009288     |CDNI                     |3018735                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Diluted Net Income,505074]                                                                          |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|30         |4298009288     |XTAX                     |3019589                    |null                    |null                      |null           |false      |false           |false            |false                 |[Income Taxes - Total,505074]                                                                        |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|33         |4298009288     |RNTS                     |3015275                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Revenues,505074]                                                                                    |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|34         |4298009288     |XTLR                     |3016345                    |null                    |null                      |null           |true       |false           |false            |false                 |[Total revenues,505074]                                                                              |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |INC                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|35         |4298009288     |XTCII                    |3016326                    |null                    |null                      |21521455386    |true       |false           |false            |null                  |[Common Shares Issued - (Instrument Level),505074]                                                   |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |BAL                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|36         |4298009288     |XTCTIPF                  |1002023922                 |null                    |null                      |21521455386    |true       |false           |false            |null                  |[Common Treasury Shares on Instrument Level Multiplied to its Conversion to Primary Factor,505074]   |null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |BAL                 |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|37         |4298009288     |XTCOIPF                  |1002023921                 |null                    |null                      |21521455386    |true       |false           |false            |null                  |[Common Shares Outstanding on Instrument Level Multiplied to its Conversion to Primary Factor,505074]|null                 |null                      |null                      |null       |BAL                 |I|!|       |
+------------------+-------------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

My issue is columns name `fl:LineItemName` .
This is a struct type and i need to create two different columns out of this .
One for the `_VALUE` as LineItemName and another for the `_languageId` as LanguageId.

Same way I have to create for `fl:LocalLanguageLabel` and for the `fl:SegmentChildDescription`.

Do I have to do this using with column option?
Or is there any way without that I can do?

This is working for me except for the last line:

```
val dfType = dfContentItem.select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"env:Data.fl:LineItem.*", getFFActionParent($"_action").as("FFAction|!|")).filter($"env:Data.fl:LineItem._organizationId".isNotNull)

val dfnewTemp = dfType
  .withColumn("LineItemName", $"fl:LineItemName._VALUE")
  .withColumn("LineItemName.languageId", $"fl:LineItemName._languageId")
  .withColumn("LocalLanguageLabel", $"fl:LocalLanguageLabel._languageId")
  .withColumn("LocalLanguageLabel.languageId", $"fl:LocalLanguageLabel._VALUE")   
  .withColumn("SegmentChildDescription", $"fl:SegmentChildDescription._languageId")
  .withColumn("SegmentChildDescription.languageId", $"fl:SegmentChildDescription._VALUE")
  .drop($"fl:LineItemName")
  .drop($"fl:LocalLanguageLabel")
  .drop($"fl:SegmentChildDescription")
dfnewTemp.show(false)
val temp = dfnewTemp.select(dfnewTemp.columns.filter(x => !x.equals("fl:Segments")).map(x => col(x).as(x.replace("_", "LineItem_").replace("fl:", ""))): _*)
```

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to take the `fl:LineItemName` column and split it into two (`LineItemName` and `LanguageId`)?

Comment: @Shaido yesexactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to use `withColumn` and simply select the variables present inside the structs. The `fl:LineItemName` column contains a struct with two values, `_VALUE` and `_languageId` which can simply be selected as follows:

```
val df = dfType.withColumn("LineItemName", $"fl:LineItemName._VALUE")
  .withColumn("LanguageId", $"fl:LineItemName._languageId")
  .drop("fl:LineItemName")
```

For the other two mentioned columns, simply do the same thing.

Comment: yes thank you and also we need to drop `($"fl:LineItemName")` .I was thinking can we do this in explode itself ...

Comment: @SUDARSHAN: that is correct. It would also be possible to use `explode` however, it's not so convenient here since the column name differ from the variable names in the struct.

Comment: same we have to follow for `fl:LocalLanguageLabel` and `fl:SegmentChildDescription` also

Comment: @SUDARSHAN: Yes, as I mentioned you need to do the same thing for the other two columns (but make sure to use different column names).

Comment: Just one more clarification .Updated my question with latest change ..I am doing this at last line but getting error like `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from LineItemName#368: need struct type but got string;`

Comment: @SUDARSHAN: Looks correct to me and unfortunately I can't test right now. Maybe you can try without the `as` renaming and see if it works.

Comment: You are right ...I have created another question for this ...Please have a look when you are free  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883875/extracting-value-from-data-frame-thorws-error-because-of-the-in-the-column-nam/48884287#48884287

Comment: @SUDARSHAN: It's possible it's as simple as changing the name of some of the nme columns. Remove the `.` and use `_` (or something else) instead. For example, change `withColumn(SegmentChildDescription.languageId, ...)` to `withColumn(SegmentChildDescription_languageId, ...)`.